# How do I exlude records from my database if a checkbox is false?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this split form with some basic search functions based on comboboxes and search fields. Now I want to exclude the records where my checkbox `chk_NonC` = false.

The VBA-code I currently use to filter my record source `qry_Administration`:

```
    Function SearchCriteria()

    Dim Customer, CustomerLocation, CustomerLocationPlace, ExecutionDate, Material As String
    Dim Intern, Extern As String
    Dim task, strCriteria As String

    If Me.chk_AuditEX = True Then
        Extern = "[AuditEX] = " & Me.chk_AuditEX
    Else
        Extern = "[AuditEX] like '*'"
    End If
    
     If Me.chk_AuditIN = True Then
        Intern = "[AuditIN] = " & Me.chk_AuditIN
    Else
        Intern = "[AuditIN] like '*'"
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.cbo_CustomerLocations) Then
        CustomerLocation = "[CustomerLocationID] like '*'"
        CustomerLocationPlace = "[LocationCompanyPlace] like '*'"
    Else
        CustomerLocation = "[LocationCompanyName] = '" & Me.cbo_CustomerLocations.Column(0) & "'"
        CustomerLocationPlace = "[LocationCompanyPlace] = '" & Me.cbo_CustomerLocations.Column(1) & "'"
    End If
    
    
    If IsNull(Me.cbo_Customers) Then
        Customer = "[CustomerID] like '*'"
    Else
        Customer = "[CustomerID] = " & Me.cbo_Customers
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.txt_ExecutionDateTo) Then
        ExecutionDate = "[ExecutionDate] like '*'"
    Else
        If IsNull(Me.txt_ExecutionDateFrom) Then
            ExecutionDate = "[ExecutionDate] like '" & Me.txt_ExecutionDateTo & "'"
        Else
            ExecutionDate = "([ExecutionDate] >= #" & Format(Me.txt_ExecutionDateFrom, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# And [ExecutionDate] <= #" & Format(Me.txt_ExecutionDateTo, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#)"
        End If
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.cbo_Material) Or Me.cbo_Material = "" Then
        Material = "[MaterialID] like '*'"
    ElseIf Me.cbo_Material = 6 Then
        Material = "[MaterialID] in (" & TempVars!tempMaterial & ")"
    Else
        Material = "([MaterialID] = " & Me.cbo_Material & ")"
    End If

    strCriteria = Customer & "And" & CustomerLocation & "And" & CustomerLocationPlace & "And" & _
            & ExecutionDate & Material & "And" & Extern & "And" & Intern
                
    task = "Select * from qry_Administration where (" & strCriteria & ") order by ExecutionDate DESC"

    Debug.Print (task)
    
    Me.Form.RecordSource = task
    Me.Form.Requery
End Function
```

Now I want to add this new checkbox Non-Compliant named `chk_NonC`

When I set `chk_NonC` to `true` and press search I want my split-form to show all records.

When I set `chk_NonC` to `false` and press search I want my split-form to hide all records where `Non_compliant` is `true`

You can see it as a hide function for my database. If I set this checkbox to false then hide all records where non-compliant is set to true.

Please note that function `SearchCriteria` is called on the OnChange Events of the comboboxes or by clicking a search-icon on the top of my split-form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the same flow defined for the other controls.

Create the string portion for the compliance and append it to the rest of the sql script.

```
Dim strCompliant As String
strCompliant = IIf(Me.chk_NonC,"[Non_compliant]=True","[Non_compliant]=False")

strCriteria = Customer & " And " [...] & " And " & strCompliant
```

Keep in mind, you need spaces between the `" And "` joins in `strCriteria`.